# How to snap to grid in StarUML?

Tags: uml, diagrams, staruml, snap-to-grid

I'm using StarUML to make some diagrams and have the grid enabled but I can't find any option to make objects snap to grid...

Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see to make that happens is under "Tools -> Options".  Set the Grid width and Grid height to both be 10.  Then you will get the snap to grid behavior your are looking for.  The grid points on the diagram are set to be 10x10 squares, so if you set your Grid width/height to 10 and 10, when you move objects they only move in units of 10, hence making it basically work like snap to grid.  Hope this works for you!

Comment: FYI, I have been using WhiteStarUML which is a derivative of StarUML -- the solution I proposed works for both.

Comment: Works fine... the problem was I didn't try with value 10... 4, 5, 6 does not "turn on" the snap to grid... Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need but the snap to grid wasn't that user-friendly. I figured out I could import my staruml project in modern web-based UML tools (hit "import staruml uml" in gg, some tools convert StarUML to UML2 diagrams online) with convenient diagramming capabilities such as fine-grained snap-to-grid. 
I know there's a new StarUML2 beta but it still has to be installed on your desktop and it doesn't seem to be compatible with StarUML1 (UML 1.3) files. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I am currently on version 2.7.0 on the Mac and the configuration of the grid work around seems to be missing nowadays. 
Vote for it to return here: https://staruml.uservoice.com/forums/245359-feature-request/suggestions/7841877-snap-to-grid